# WSO2: APIM Logging

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have setup APIM (2.5.0)and Analytics. I have some users and few of the APIs created by the user.
For instance, one of the user onboarded one of the free API which is providing the weather information.
Another user subscribed it from store and started consuming it. At the end of the day, there were around 20 hits from the user to consume weather API.

But, among this 20 hits, 2 hits didnot fetch any result from the weather API URL (URL which we configure in Production and Sandbox URL of the publisher) as the connection was down but the as the APIM was running and allowed the user to consume, the logging continued and produced 20 hits for the user but technically it should be 18 hits only ( as 2 hits were not completed).

How to overcome this case, where the APIs are external and they onboarded in WSO2 APIM (using swagger or manually created) and logging is maintained so that TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT should come out to be same of the positive hits/response.

Any information on this topic would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are maintaining `TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT` it means the request you are getting which is `20` & it's correct. There should be another parameter you should have which will be `TOTAL_RESPONSE_COUNT` it will maintain the response count. So that you will get to know how many request are coming & how many got responded. Also if you want to see successful response count, have something `TOTAL_SUCCESS_RESPONSE_COUNT.

If you are having backend services in tomcat, then always make sure that thread count in WSO2 should be always greater than thread count of tomcat. WSO2 threads can be configured in `<WSO2AM_HOME>/repository/conf/nhttp.properties`. Look at last couple of lines in this file.

Also, you can change your retry policy by making changes into API publisher `:9443/publisher` by editing existing API.

Comment: TOTAL_SUCCESS_RESPONSE_COUNT table present in STATS DB. I could not find it.